# How to start a docker container with docker-java library?

Tags: java, docker, boot2docker

Develop Environment:

docker-java library 2.0.1

docker-machine 0.4.1

docker 1.8.1

I'm trying:

```
CreateContainerResponse container = client.createContainerCmd("busybox").withCmd("top").exec();         
client.startContainerCmd(container.getId()).exec();
ExecCreateCmdResponse execCreateCmdResponse = client.execCreateCmd(container.getId())
                    .withCmd("touch", "file.log").exec();
```

But the container is stopped so I'm getting the next exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.github.dockerjava.api.InternalServerErrorException: Container 30e43b7aa427331be5e1096f4b4944613841d33649a804c28dce939d0d1d6b5f is not running

    at com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.filter.ResponseStatusExceptionFilter.filter(ResponseStatusExceptionFilter.java:53)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientFilteringStages$ResponseFilterStage.apply(ClientFilteringStages.java:134)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientFilteringStages$ResponseFilterStage.apply(ClientFilteringStages.java:123)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:171)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:251)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$2.call(JerseyInvocation.java:683)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:424)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:679)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:435)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.post(JerseyInvocation.java:338)
    at com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.ExecCreateCmdExec.execute(ExecCreateCmdExec.java:30)
    at com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.ExecCreateCmdExec.execute(ExecCreateCmdExec.java:14)
    at com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.AbstrSyncDockerCmdExec.exec(AbstrSyncDockerCmdExec.java:24)
    at com.github.dockerjava.core.command.AbstrDockerCmd.exec(AbstrDockerCmd.java:33)
    at com.github.dockerjava.core.command.ExecCreateCmdImpl.exec(ExecCreateCmdImpl.java:122)
    at com.github.dockerjava.core.command.ExecCreateCmdImpl.exec(ExecCreateCmdImpl.java:10)
    at org.fluxtrean.poc.docker.java.App.main(App.java:58)
```

What else I can try?